# ERROR 1: Attempt to create 5259x-3397 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, gdal-merge

I am attempting to merge two .tiff files using gdal_merge.py (GDAL 3.4.3, released 2022/04/22), but I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR 1: Attempt to create 5259x-3397 dataset is illegal,sizes must be larger than zero.

I have extracted the files from two different .nc files using Python and individually they display correctly in QGIS. If i run `gdalinfo` on  these files I get this:

First file:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: bdda42b7-4f08-43b7-9514-73701e71e4d1.tiff
Size is 372, 263
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]

Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (0.650225100732557,38.530213880174941)
Pixel Size = (0.003317122028844,0.002995396388396)

Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area

Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND

Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (   0.6502251,  38.5302139) (  0d39' 0.81"E, 38d31'48.77"N)
Lower Left  (   0.6502251,  39.3180031) (  0d39' 0.81"E, 39d19' 4.81"N)
Upper Right (   1.8841945,  38.5302139) (  1d53' 3.10"E, 38d31'48.77"N)
Lower Right (   1.8841945,  39.3180031) (  1d53' 3.10"E, 39d19' 4.81"N)
Center      (   1.2672098,  38.9241085) (  1d16' 1.96"E, 38d55'26.79"N)

Band 1 Block=372x5 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  Description = u
  NoData Value=-9999
```

Second file:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: cbaf4d5b-aa05-4429-89ba-fb4f6266aaf0.tiff
Size is 208, 403
Coordinate System is:

GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]

Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-15.562136997923183,27.583453885358363)
Pixel Size = (0.002543191403007,0.001904027378974)

Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area

Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND

Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -15.5621370,  27.5834539) ( 15d33'43.69"W, 27d35' 0.43"N)
Lower Left  ( -15.5621370,  28.3507769) ( 15d33'43.69"W, 28d21' 2.80"N)
Upper Right ( -15.0331532,  27.5834539) ( 15d 1'59.35"W, 27d35' 0.43"N)
Lower Right ( -15.0331532,  28.3507769) ( 15d 1'59.35"W, 28d21' 2.80"N)
Center      ( -15.2976451,  27.9671154) ( 15d17'51.52"W, 27d58' 1.62"N)

Band 1 Block=208x9 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  Description = u
  NoData Value=-9999
```

Both files are in the same coordinate system and have a matching number of bands, although they have a different size.

Any ideas why I can't merge these files?

Comment: Maybe the positive pixel size `Pixel Size = (0.003317122028844,0.002995396388396)` is a surprise for the gdal_merge script. In that case it is a bug, it is correct to have image origin at the lower left corner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to merge rasters with negative extents?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34722/how-to-merge-rasters-with-negative-extents)

Comment: Are the two images in the same location or in different locations?